# Expo local notification in background

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

I am using expo for react-native application. I wanted to add a functionality where I could show notification when actual time will be the same as a hardcoded time in code. The problem is that it works when I have my app in expo opened but doesn't when it is in background.
Here is the notifications handler that should run it in background:

```
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});
```

Here is my useEffect for setting push notifications:

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token: any) => {
      setExpoPushToken(token);
    });

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(
      (notification: any) => {
        setNotification(notification);
      }
    );

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener);
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener);
    };
  }, []);
```

And here is the code for registering and sending notifications with token:

```
async function sendPushNotification() {
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        title: "You've got mail! ",
        body: "Here is the notification body",
        data: { data: "goes here" },
      },
      trigger: { seconds: 1 },
    });
  }

  async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
        Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
      );
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(
          Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
        );
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      console.log(token);
    }
    else {
    alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
     }

    return token;
  }
```

So I just use sendPushNotification() function for sending it. It works when I the app is open but after minimising it it doesn't show anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Comment: @alexanderdavide didn't find any till now

Comment: That's a bummer and makes Expo's managed workflow pretty much unusable when having to deal with notifications. I'm moving to bare workflow now.